# Laravel 5.3 active record OR

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Can I ask how to do it on **laravel 5.3** in **objects**? i used local scope method. So far i am confused using or in their objects.
thanks.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `conversations` WHERE (`conversations`.`user_id` = 1 AND `conversations`.`chat_id` = 2) OR (`conversations`.`user_id` = 2 AND `conversations`.`chat_id` = 1)";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$conversation = Conversation::where(function($q) {
        $q->where('user_id', 1);
        $q->where('chat_id', 2);
    })->orWhere(function($q) {
        $q->where('user_id', 2);
        $q->where('chat_id', 1);
    })->get();
```

If you want to use variables, don't forget to pass them with `use()`.